# How to access an Excel file on Onedrive with Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, data-preprocessing

I want to open an Excel file (on Onedrive) with Openpyxl (Python). I received error trying this:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = r"https://d.docs.live.net/dd10xxxxxxxxxx"
wb = load_workbook(filename = file)
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
```

> `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://d.docs.live.net/dd10...`

Answer (score 2):

OpenPyXL cannot read/write files over http. It  expects a file on a traditional filesystem, whether it's local, on a network share, etc.

If you're using OneDrive For Business you could try [mapping it to a drive letter](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0), or investigate the use of Google Sheets and the [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) library instead.

Answer (score 1):

If no authentication to be concerned about, copy the shared URL from Onedrive and convert to a direct download URL then request direct url as a bytes file which Openpyxl can upload.
The example onedrive url is from my local drive just for clarity.

**Note** the conversion function is copied from [OneDrive as Data Storage for Python Project](https://towardsdatascience.com/onedrive-as-data-storage-for-python-project-2ff8d2d3a0aa) by Joe T. Santhanavanich

```
import base64
import io
import urllib.request
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def create_onedrive_directdownload(onedrive_link):
    data_bytes64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(onedrive_link, 'utf-8'))
    data_bytes64_String = data_bytes64.decode('utf-8').replace('/', '_').replace('+', '-').rstrip("=")
    resultUrl = f"https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!{data_bytes64_String}/root/content"
    return resultUrl


### Original link copied from the file in onedrive
onedrive_link = "https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoNMV-zn1OSxhANyuaBK4RQiKmDb?e=tZ2mrv"
### Converted Onedrive link
onedrive_direct_link = create_onedrive_directdownload(onedrive_link)
### Retrieve url as bytes file
file = urllib.request.urlopen(onedrive_direct_link).read()

### Load file into Openpyxl
wb = load_workbook(filename=io.BytesIO(file))
ws = wb['Sheet1']

print(f"Value in Cell A1: '{ws['A1'].value}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way is to use google drive rather than one drive then open google colab, mount the google drive and open the file from google drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```